# 32 gb internal storage having 10.82 gb of total files but shows only 5 gb free

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, internal-storage, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have samsung sm900(galaxy note 3) and out of 32 gb internal storage, only 10.82 gb is used but it shows only 5 gb space free. Please solve this.

[image: Image of 5 gb free of 32 gb.]

[image: Image of total used storage.]

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage).

Answer (score 0):

That is only the `/sdcard` partition. Since you are not rooted, that is all you can access. But actually there are a lot of other partitions that are occupying the 32 GB space you have. They include but not limited to, `/system`, `/boot`, `/cache`, `/root` etc. You can consider them like `C:\` and other drives from PC. What you access using File Manager and is equal to 10.82GB is only the `/sdcard` partition (`storage/emulated/0`) so there is nothing to help since there is nothing unordinary.